# elementsFromPoint doesn't contain mouseover element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to get a list of elements at the mouse pointer coordinate. [`document.elementsFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementsFromPoint) seems to do the trick, but I noticed that the mouseover event's target isn't always included in the list, even though I passed in the event's `clientX` and `clientY`.

I'd like to understand why this is the case. Is manually adding the event target to the list is the best workaround?

To reproduce: move the mouse in a circular motion around "More stuff":

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    let elems = document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    if(elems.indexOf(e.target) === -1) {
      console.log(elems); 
      console.log(e.target); 
      console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }
    
});
```

```css
span {
margin-top: 2px;
float: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div>
  More
  <span>stuff</span>
</div>
<div>
  More
  <span>stuff</span>
</div>
<div>
  More
  <span>stuff</span>
</div>
<div>
  More
  <span>stuff</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It seem hapens only with inline element when trying to access its area on the  left ,seem a bug in browser  ?

Comment: test with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0cmyaL2/) in ffox does work ,
but work well on chrome , so you're using ffox ?

Comment: I'm using chrome

Comment: that's weird I'musing chrme v68 an works well !

Comment: I have the same situation, I was testing your code snippet a little bit, and it seems that it happens only when there is no rendered text behind the mouse coordinates